# Display security groups for a specific instance using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am trying to find out which security groups a specific aws ec2 instance is in. I know I can do

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances
```

and then filter this result and do various things to it by piping the result to grep, but what has frustrated me is that I cannot use

```
 aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id [instance-id] --attribute securityGroups
```

or

```
 aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id [instance-id] --attribute Groups
```

, despite the documentation at: [describe-instance-attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-attribute.html) suggesting that you can. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What has AWS support said about it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such attribute called **`Groups`**. Refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-attribute.html

from above link:

[image]

Same is mentioned in EC2 API Reference Guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstanceAttribute.html

From Above link:

[image]

Probably **`groupSet`** attribute is what you are looking for:

e,g:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id [instance-id] --attribute groupSet
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! That is the doc page I have been unable to find for hours (I get lost in amazon doc sometimes). Can you please extend the answer so that I can accept it (i.e. aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id [instance-id] --attribute groupSet)